# PHP MYSQL: how to display chat room messages based on ignore list

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a basic php chat room. Each "room" has its own table. within each room table, there are individual messages posted, one row per one message. the columns are as follows:

```
id, sender, message
```

in a separate table called ignore_lists, users have a command in the chat to add users to their ignore list for private message purposes. Which works great, I have that part fully working.

But today I decided I wanted to try to make it also stop them from seeing messages on the "main screen" public chat for people they have on their ignore lists.

I've tried and tried but can't get it to work without doing all sorts of funky stuff.

Here is the function that displays my chat messages:

```
function showroom($room, $len, $link){
  $query3 = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT `message`, `id`, `sender` FROM `$room` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $len) AS `id` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
  $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3); // execute the query
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
      $showmsg = htmlspecialchars_decode($row["message"]);
      echo "$showmsg<br>";
    }}}
```

**How can I use the ignore list table to somehow pull up messages from the function above but exclude any number of people who appear on the ignore list?**

for further reference.. the ignore list table simply is one big table for all users. everytime a user adds someone to their ignore list, it inserts a row into the ignore_list table with columns:
`id, person_being_ignored, name_of_ignore_list_owner`

I made a statement like this but it didn't work. Or rather I should say it does work, but it only works if you have exactly one person on the ignore list.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM `ignore_lists` WHERE `ignore_owner`='$id' ORDER BY `person_being_ignored` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // execute the query

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  while($mrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $ignoree_name = $mrow['name_of_ignored'];

    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM `$room` WHERE sender <> '$ignoree_name'";
    // $query3 = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT `message`, `id`, `timestamp`, `color` FROM `$room` WHERE sender <> '$ignoree_name' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $len) AS `id` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3); // execute the query
  }
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
    $showmsg = htmlspecialchars_decode($row["message"]);
    echo "$showmsg<br>";
  }

} elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {

  $query3 = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT `message`, `id`, `timestamp`, `color` FROM `$room` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $len) AS `id` ORDER BY `id` ASC";
  $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3); // execute the query

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
      $showmsg = htmlspecialchars_decode($row["message"]);
      echo "$showmsg<br>";
    }}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't we used WHERE NOT IN SQL statements ...

```
$ignoree_name = [];
while($mrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ignoree_name[] = $mrow['name_of_ignored'];
}
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT message, id, timestamp, color FROM $room WHERE sender NOT IN ( '" . implode($ignoree_name, "', '") . "' ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 99) AS id ORDER BY id ASC";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3); // execute the query
```

Warning ... I haven't tested it yet ...

Comment: thank you. it will be a couple of hours before i can get home and give this a try. but i will let you know as soon as i try it. i didnt know i could use an array in a mysql statement.

Comment: It's not an array, I'm used implode to join array elements and return the result as string so it can be used in MySQL statement. More in here [php implode](http://php.net/implode)

Comment: this semi worked. I had to modify it though. it wouldnt come back with a valid mysql result using ($wherein) in the query. i had to do it like this

`$query3 = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT message, id, timestamp, color FROM $room WHERE sender NOT IN ( '" . implode($ignoree_name, "', '") . "' ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 99) AS id ORDER BY id ASC";` 

just in case you want to edit your answer

Comment: Yes I forgot the quotation.